# C# How does removing an Item of a ListView works?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview

I have a List with a few items presented on a ListView.

Each item has a few fields of course
I would like to know what happens when I remove an item of my list.
I search a specific item that matches any field inside the list and then removes it.
How does that happen? What is deleted? the reference of that item? the whole items ?

the description:

> removes a first occurrence of a specific object

isnt clear to me

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the item, if you don't have a reference set to it elsewhere, it will be eligible for [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx). It's no longer on your ListViews Items collection. This means it's not rendered in the ListView.

The Remove method specifically removes the reference to your item inside the ListViews internal collection which holds the items.

Your Item will eventually be garbage collected and gone from the memory of your computer.